# jquery combine zrssfeed and touch gallery

Tags: jquery, parsing, touch, gallery

How do I combine rssfeed and touchGallery jQuery functions so that the gallery recognizes the rss parsed content?  The rss parsing function writes a .rssBody within #test.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#test').rssfeed('http://foo.com/foo-rss', {
    limit: 5
});
$('.rssBody a').touchGallery();
```

});

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Below is an example code from NETEYE Touch Gallery that does a similar thing using flickr API and touch gallery.

```
    $(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=ed144a125aca366df3438c58c0c0ec9d&photoset_id=72157624601158052&extras=url_sq,url_m,url_o,&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
        $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i) {
            $('<div>').append($('<img>').attr('src', this.url_sq)).data('flickr', this).appendTo('#gallery');
        });
        $('#gallery div').touchGallery({
            getSource: function() {
                var f = $(this).data('flickr');
                return f.url_o || f.url_sq.replace('_s.', '_b.');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

zRSSFeed allows for a callback to occur after the RSS has loaded. This should do the trick:

```
$('#test').rssfeed('http://foo.com/foo-rss', {
    limit: 5
}, function() {$('#test .rssBody li').touchGallery()});
```